# Is there a way to pass data between 2 cell renderers in ag grid?

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-angular, ag-grid-ng2, cellrenderer

I have 2 cell renderers in 2 coulmns of my ag grid. 1st column is action column. 2nd column is a dropdown containing data options.

Dynamically, based on the selection of data from dropdown in 2nd column, i want to change / toggle the action icons in the 1st column. Is this possible?

I have used cellrendererframework for both cell renderers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible!

First of all, you should add `refresh()` method to you `cell-dropdown.component`

It will look like:

```
public refresh(params): boolean {  
    params.api.redrawRows();

    return true;
}
```

After new selection have been selected it calls the method `refresh()` and the first column will redraw

I have created exapmle with your case:

We have dropdown of gender and based on changed selection -  name of the first column will change

For gender column is used `cellRenderFrameWork`

for the first column (name) is used simple inline `cellRender` and looks like

```
  { field: 'name', cellRenderer: params => {
    return params.data.gender === "Female" ? params.value : 'Roman' 
  } },
```

[image]

[image]

working example: https://plnkr.co/edit/HT5fgs0VV5PqErWH

Comment: It worked! But my scenario was a little bit different. I did not use inline cell renderer but another cell renderer framework, passing params.api.redrawrows was making the action column back to its original state which i did not want.

Comment: But your answer will also help me to proceed with my next challenge. I accept this answer and hence this is correct! 

Comment: Im sorry i have very low reputation, so it is not letting me to upvote this answer. I would reach out to you if i face any ag grid issues. Again, thanks a tonne :)